# Symfony DoctrineChoince Validator 'Where' condition

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I want to make a "forgot password" form. For the `username` field I used the code:

```
    $this->form->setValidators(array(
        'username'   => new sfValidatorAnd(
            array(
                new sfValidatorString(array('min_length' => 4),
                    array(
                        'min_length' => 'Minim %min_length% caractere.',)),
                new sfValidatorDoctrineChoice(array(
                    'model'=>'Users',
                    'column'=>'username'), array(
                    'invalid' => 'Utilizatorul nu există.',
                    )),
            ),
            array(),
            array(
                    'required' => 'Câmp obligatoriu',
            )
    ),
```

but for the `email` field I want to use the `sfValidatorDoctrineChoice` with a custom query, where the `WHERE` condition is: username = the 'username' field value gathered from the form.

What variable contains this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$this->form->getValue('username')`

Answer (score 0):

`$request->getParameter('FormName')` then the array contains all the submitted data.

Answer (score 0):

`$this->form->getValue('username')` works only for bound and validated data.